# What is this plot called and how can I make it with ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, scatter

Consider a plot like the one on top:

[image]

I want to recreate this kind of plot (curvy scatter plot) which indicates the spread of the samples through the curves around the median. So far, my search has not been successful.

Does anyone know :

1. How this plot is called ?
2. How this plot could be created with `ggplot2` ?
3. Can this scatter plot with equidistant points per categorical variable be done with `geom_point()` ?

Original source: https://www.nature.com/articles/nature12213/figures/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it just ordering and spacing out the points that are otherwise discrete? You can fairly easily make your own geoms (see [this guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html))/ Maybe something like

```
StatSlide <- ggproto("StatSlide", Stat,
  compute_group = function(data, scales) {
    data$y <- sort(data$y)
    data$x <- data$x + seq( -.4, .4, length.out = nrow(data))
    data
  },
  required_aes = c("x", "y")
)

stat_slide <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "point",
                       position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                       inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    stat = StatSlide, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
}

# test it out
ggplot(mpg) + 
  stat_slide(aes(drv, displ, color=drv))
```

[image]